# Titanium: Any way to build an app with custom parameters that are accessible in-app?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I build my Appcelerator Titanium app using

`appc ti build -p ios -T simulator`

Is there any way to pass custom variables (like an environment or development-config) to the build process, so that they actually become available in the compiled javascript files?

I need to specifically be able to define such thing from the command line, and not from a file somewhere in the project. I previously tried a write command to  `app/config.json` using a grunt script, but it's a subpar solution, and it requires me to revert changes after the build process.

Use case: i want to send an API key to the build process which can be used in-app, but this APIkey will be nowhere in the working copy or git repository.

Answer (score 0):

this should be helpful. let me know if this works-out for you.

[TiCh](https://github.com/jasonkneen/TiCh)

Comment: im gonna get shot for using such dirty module. All I need is 1 setting which can be passed to the build per programmer independently. I've thought about creating a titanium plugin myself, but one of the issues im getting is that I need to get this working with "liveview" as well